# I am trying to encrypt secretKey created on android client with the publicKey(RSA) generated on nodejs server and decrypt that secretKey on server?

Tags: android, node.js, encryption, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric

I am trying to encrypt secretKey created on android client with the publicKey(RSA) generated on nodeJs server and decrypt that secretKey on nodeJs server.

This is the Android Client Side Code .

```
override suspend fun encryptClientKey(publicKeyString: String): String {
        println("Inside encryptClientKey fun publicKeyString as Base64 : $publicKeyString")
        val publicKeyDecodedBuffer = Base64.decode(publicKeyString, Base64.DEFAULT)
        println("Inside encryptClientKey fun publicKeyDecoded as Buffer 
:$publicKeyDecodedBuffer")
        var pemFile = String(publicKeyDecodedBuffer)
        println("Inside encryptClientKey fun pemFile as String: $pemFile")
        pemFile = pemFile
            .replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "")
            .replace("\n", "")
            .replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "")
        println("Inside encryptClientKey() pemFile as String: $pemFile")
        val decodedKeyMaterialInsidePemFile = Base64.decode(pemFile, Base64.DEFAULT)
        println("Inside encryptClientKey fun decodedPemFile of servers publicKey as Buffer: ${String(decodedKeyMaterialInsidePemFile)}")
        val publicKeySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedKeyMaterialInsidePemFile)
        val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")
        val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)
        val cipherForClientKeyEncryption = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")
        cipherForClientKeyEncryption.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey)
        val decryptedSecretKeyInBase64 = decryptOpener(encryptedOpener = getEncryptedOpenerKey())
        println("Inside encryptClientKey() decryptedSecretKeyInBase64: $decryptedSecretKeyInBase64")
        val decipheredSKeyInBuffer = Base64.decode(decryptedSecretKeyInBase64, Base64.DEFAULT)
        return Base64.encodeToString(cipherForClientKeyEncryption.doFinal(decipheredSKeyInBuffer), Base64.DEFAULT)
    }
```

This is the NodeJs Server Side

```
async decryptClientKey(secretKey: string, privateKey: string, userId: string): Promise<Buffer> {
        console.log(Buffer.from(privateKey, 'base64').toString())
        const keyInPemFormat = Buffer.from(privateKey, 'base64').toString()
        const sKeyBufferFromB64 = Buffer.from(secretKey, 'base64')
        const sKeyHexForm = sKeyBufferFromB64.toString('hex')
        const privateKeyObject = createPrivateKey({
            key: keyInPemFormat,
            format: 'pem',
            passphrase: userId
        })
        const sKey = privateDecrypt(
            {
                key: privateKeyObject,
                padding: constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING,
            },
            Buffer.from(sKeyHexForm, 'hex')
        )
        return sKey
    }
```

This is how I generated Pair in NodeJs

```
  async generateKeyPair(userId: string): Promise<string> {
    const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync(
      'rsa',
      {
        modulusLength: 2048,
        publicKeyEncoding: {
          type: 'spki', // same as what Java calls X509Encoded
          format: 'pem',
        },
        privateKeyEncoding: {
          type: 'pkcs8',
          format: 'pem',
          cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
          passphrase: userId,
        },
      }
    )
    const privateKeyBase64Form = (Buffer.from(privateKey)).toString('base64')
    const publicKeyBase64Form = (Buffer.from(publicKey)).toString('base64')
    return `${publicKeyBase64Form}%${privateKeyBase64Form}`
  }
```

Comment: What is the question? Post missing functions (`decryptOpener()`, `getEncryptedOpenerKey()`) or simplify the code with a dummy value for `decryptedSecretKeyInBase64` *so that the code is compilable*! Is the PEM key itself really Base64 encoded (this wouldn't be required since the PEM key itself is essentially a Base64 encoding of the DER encoded key)? Post test keys (i.e. a value for `publicKeyString` and the corresponding private key) for checking.

Comment: @Topaco Thanks So much for giving time. I actually got the way how to implement this after some research.